# Iterate And Filter Array 2D Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-9

I have an Array like so:

```
int[] array_example = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
Long count_array = Arrays.stream(array_example)
                      .filter(x -> x>5)
                      .count();
```

and a 2d array like so:

```
int[][] matrix_example = {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}};
Long count_matrix = 0L;
for(int[] temp: matrix_example){
    for(int x_y: temp){
        if(x_y > 5)
           count_matrix++;
    }
}
```

How could I obtain the number of elements greater than x of a matrix with java 8 or higher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `IntStream` of the matrix using [`flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt(java.util.function.Function)) then use `filter` and `count` as earlier :

```
Long count_matrix = Arrays.stream(matrix_example) // Stream<int[]>
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream) // IntStream
        .filter(x_y -> x_y > 5) // filtered as per your 'if'
        .count(); // count of such elements
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
long count = Arrays.stream(matrix_example)
                   .mapToLong(a -> Arrays.stream(a).filter(x -> x > 5).count()).sum();
```

- creates a stream from `matrix_example` via `Arrays.stream`
- maps each array to the number of times a given element is greater than `5` via `mapToLong`
- then we take all those amounts and sum them up to get the count via `sum`